# Are ultrasonic ant repellents effective?

Tags: pest-control, ants

I'm considering an ultrasonic ant repellent for the kitchen (where I'd rather not use a chemical pesticide).

Do these things work?

Comment: If you'd prefer to not use chemicals, diatomaceous earth and/or cinnamon supposedly work.

Comment: cinnamon helps only a bit, and for a limited time. is diatomaceous earth better? is it suitable for the kitchen counter?

Comment: diatomaceous earth is extremely sharp shards to an ant, so will kill it if it tries to traverse it. I'd probably not put it on counters, but it'd be fine on the floors and/or outside.

Comment: Side note: I asked my pest exterminater about outside recently, he indicated you would need a WIDE band (10-15 feet at least) of pesticide to really control ants from the outside.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about how effective they are specifically on ants -- but I do know one major drawback with these devices: they don't work around corners or behind objects.  In other words, they are line of sight only.  If the ants are behind cabinets, appliances, in the walls, etc, these devices won't work.

My own approach to this issue has been to use pesticide in the yard so they don't get into the house in the first place.  That, and I try to make sure the house is clean (floors vacuumed, counters wiped, food in sealed containers, etc).